# Windows Wallet, Beta 7, stuck at 460,000 out of 663,000?

Tags: wallets, mist, windows, bug

[image]

My friend downloaded the Windows Beta 7 wallet and as you can see in the picture he is stuck at block 460.000. Also the "out of" blocks statistic keeps jumping between 663,000 to 1,000,000+.

Even when shutting down and starting again it stays the same.

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Could very well be a bug. Problem sounds similar to [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/109). Have you checked peers/network connectivity and tried running `wallet/resources/nodes/geth/geth.exe` to check for errors?

Comment: "no items match your search" came up

Comment: Report your problem on the Github page for the devs to know.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with windows, which is already fixed in geth#develop branch. Please wait for one release after homestead. This one will then include the fix.

Optional you can build from the develop branch yourself.